# How to nest asynchronous functions based on array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, plural

I have a async function that breaks it's callbacks into an object `success` and `error`, this function takes one param (besides the callback) `"pink"`.

```
async("pink",{
    success:function(){

    },
    error:function(){

    }
});
```

I want to make plural version of this function that takes in an array and returns the `true` or `false` value for the `async` action.

```
asyncs(["blue","red","green"],function(values){
    console.log(values); // [true,true,true];
});
```

The trick is that each `acync` action needs to be within the next, the value of the function (`true` or `false`) needs to be `pushed()` into a "global" (higher in scope) variable `values` and the returned in a master `callback(values)` at the end (when the `count` reaches the array `length`)

This is a very rudimentary way of nesting each `async()` function and returning the `values`, it is limited because it manually trails only `3` array values.

```
var asyncs = function(params,mstrCB){
    var length = params.length;
    var values = [];
    async(param[0],{
        success:function(){
            values.push(true);
            async(param[1],{
                success:function(){
                    values.push(true);
                    async(param[2],{
                        success:function(){
                            values.push(true);
                            mstrCB(values);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            values.push(false);
                            mstrCB(values);
                        }
                    });
                },
                error:function(){
                    values.push(false);
                     mstrCB(values);
                }
            });
        },
        error:function(){
            values.push(false);
            mstrCB(values);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: if you are going to do this more often (and you are) i suggest you use this great little lib: https://github.com/willconant/flow-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter instead of manually nesting. Put the request in its own function, and up on each `success`, increment the counter and if it's less than `length`, make a new request.

When `i === length`, call the `mstrCB()`.

```
var asyncs = function(params,mstrCB){
    var length = params.length;
    var values = [];
    var i = 0;

    if (length)
        makeRequest();

    function makeRequest() {
        async(params[i], {
            success:function(){
                values.push(true);

                 // Increment the counter
                i++;

                if (i === length)  // we're at the end
                    mstrCB(values);
                else
                    makeRequest(); // there's still more, so make another request
            },
            error:function(){
                values.push(false);
                mstrCB(values);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had in my mind, I just couldn't visualize it.